# HTML5 Geolocation, GPS Only

Tags: html, mobile, geolocation, gps

Is there a way to make HTML5's Geolocation only work, if it is using a GPS device to get the location?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I don't believe it's possible, the best you can do is pass `true` for [enableHighAccuracy](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html#high-accuracy) and use a heuristic based on the [accuracy](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html#accuracy) value.

--Edit

I saw a presentation by [Remy Sharp](http://introducinghtml5.com/) last month and he had a useful suggestion: if you use `watchPosition` instead of `getCurrentPosition` then you can wait until the location information becomes accurate enough; GPS often takes some time to lock on to satellites so usually `getCurrentPosition` will just return something from one of the less accurate but more responsive methods.

Comment: Yep, I'd second this. The implementation on the browser controls how location is determined and they pretty much all try most accurate (GPS) and fall back to network based detection.

Comment: Yes, that is actually how I ended up implementing what I needed.  Watching the accuracy until it was in a desired range allowed me to verify a user's location using a mobile web app.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://code.google.com/p/mobile-gps-web-gate/